# Difference in Days in DB2

Tags: date, db2, difference

I have to calculate the difference in days between two dates and I figured out that
there is no such thing as a `DATEDIFF()` function in DB2.

I tried doing it like that:

```
(DAYOFYEAR(date1)-DAYOFYEAR(date2)+(YEAR(date1)-YEAR(date2))*365)
```

This is obviously not working for leap years, but I do not have to deal with that.

I know that date1 is always later than date2.

Do I have any flaws in my logic? It is not working (it's an exercise and I have a function to test my results). Is there an easier way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: If it is not working (how, by the way?) then you probably do have flaws in the logic.

Comment: I get different results than the test function says i should get. What i meant was: Is my method of calculating the difference in days correct? If yes, then i have some other mistake in my query, but no sense in searching for it if the calculation is just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would possibly help if we knew what version of DB2 you were using and what platform it was running on. But it seems likely that you can do something like this:

```
select
      days(my1stdate) - days(my2nddate) as myDuration
from mySchema.myTable
```

The DAYS() function converts a DATE value into the number of days between Jan 1, 0001, and the supplied DATE value. Once both DATEs are converted, the subtraction (difference) is straightforward.

Comment: Didnt know this function, its working now, thank you.